# Add ghost empty lines between some lines of QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtwidgets

I am trying to build a small text editor and I would like to know whether it is possible to add empty lines that do not count towards the widget text between some lines of the document. It would look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, there is a empty line between lines 2 and 3 that do not count as a real line, it is just needed for margin purposes

Code:

```py
import re

from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, Qt, QSize, QRect
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QTextOption, QSyntaxHighlighter
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QPlainTextEdit, QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow


class LineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, highlighter):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=highlighter)
        self.highlighter = highlighter

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.highlighter.line_number_area_width(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.highlighter.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class Highlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self):
        QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__(self, None)
        self.patterns = {}

    def highlightBlock(self, text: str):
        for pattern, fmt in self.patterns.items():
            for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
                start, end = match.span()
                self.setFormat(start, end - start, fmt)
                break


class Editor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        fmt = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        fmt.setFontCapitalization(QtGui.QFont.AllUppercase)
        self.setCurrentCharFormat(fmt)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black; color: white;")
        self.setWordWrapMode(QTextOption.WordWrap)

        self.line_number_area = LineNumberArea(self)

        self.blockCountChanged[int].connect(self.update_line_number_area_width)
        self.updateRequest[QRect, int].connect(self.update_line_number_area)

        self.update_line_number_area_width(0)

        self.highlighter = Highlighter()
        self.highlighter.setDocument(self.document())

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.line_number_area)
        rect: QRect = event.rect()
        rect.translate(0, 1)
        painter.fillRect(rect, QColor("#2b2b2b"))
        painter.setFont(self.font())

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        while block.isValid() and top <= event.rect().bottom():
            if block.isVisible() and bottom >= event.rect().top():
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.white)

                painter.drawText(0, top, self.line_number_area.width(),
                                 self.fontMetrics().height(), Qt.AlignRight, number)
            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1

    def line_number_area_width(self):
        digits = 1
        max_num = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_num >= 10:
            max_num *= 0.1
            digits += 1

        space = 5 + self.fontMetrics().horizontalAdvance('9') * digits
        return space

    @Slot(QRect, int)
    def update_line_number_area(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.line_number_area.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            width = self.line_number_area.width()
            self.line_number_area.update(0, rect.y(), width, rect.height())

        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.update_line_number_area_width(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        width = self.line_number_area_width()
        rect = QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), width, cr.height())
        self.line_number_area.setGeometry(rect)

    @Slot(int)
    def update_line_number_area_width(self, newBlockCount):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.line_number_area_width(), 0, 0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(Editor())
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Setting the top/bottom margin using a text-block-format would work with a QTextEdit (but probably not with a QPlainTextEdit).

Comment: I confirm that this could only work for QTextEdit, as QPlainTextEdit uses a much simpler text layout engine that is optimized for speed and doesn't support most block/char format features: each line is a text block, and all blocks always have the same height (except for laying out purposes when wrapping is enabled). The only possibility you have is to study the code of the QPlainTextDocumentLayout and port it to python.

Comment: @musicamante I have managed to migrate from QPlainTextEdit to QTextEdit. Now, how coud I do that?

Comment: @Jaime02 Get the text block you want to separate from the one above it, get its [`blockFormat()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html#blockFormat), call [`setTopMargin()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblockformat.html#setTopMargin) and then call `QTextCursor(block).setBlockFormat(format)`. Note that, as opposed to QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit treats line breaks (`<br>` for `setHtml()`, or Shift+Return) as part of the same block (paragraph), so you may need to take precautions both for paste (by overriding [`insertFromMimeData()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData)) *and* key events.